# Peewee: create_or_get a record with a Field that is Null

Tags: python, sql, isnull, peewee

With peewee, the sql query created by

```
MyModel.create_or_get(foo='bar', nullable=None)
```

to check, if the record exists, will effectively look like this

> SELECT ... FROM "MyModel" AS t1 WHERE (("t1"."foo" = 'bar') AND ("t1"."nullable" = None))

which will result in the expression to always create a record in `MyModel` with the value `NULL` for the field `nullable` - no matter if one existed.

Can I somehow use `create_or_get` (or another existing peewee method) with a `NULL` value without having to rewrite the routine myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `get_or_create` and passing in the `defaults={'nullable': None}`.